# trying to run gsutils from java never returns

Tags: java, macos, java-8, google-cloud-storage

I try to download folders from Google storage on the cloud.

I run from a process of a user that have permissions (when i run from regular terminal on mac it works)

I have this code:

```
public void runCommand() {
    final Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "gsutil -m cp -r gs://my_bucket/705/201609040613/output/html_pages file:/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/GsClient/build/resources/main/downloads/");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;

            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the new thread never returns.

stuck on line:

`while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)`

Is there any way to download these folders from google cloud otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This manual copying of `stdout` data is error prone (you would have to forcefully close the stream to terminate the sub thread) and thankfully, [unnecessary since Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()):

```
public void runCommand() {
    try {
        new ProcessBuilder("gsutil", "-m", "cp", "-r",
            "gs://my_bucket/705/201609040613/output/html_pages",
            "file:/Users/eladb/WorkspaceQa/GsClient/build/resources/main/downloads/")
        .inheritIO()
        .start()
        .waitFor();
    } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you don’t want to direct all three channels this way, see [`redirectOutput(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)), [`redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect)), and the similar methods for input and error channel.

---

Only the (default) mode [`ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#PIPE) requires you to provide input or receive output while the sub-process is runnig.